# Eclipse register extension point programmatically

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I am trying to write some JUnit tests for a class which accesses the extension registry.

```
IExtensionRegistry registry = Platform.getExtensionRegistry();
    IConfigurationElement[] extensions = registry.getConfigurationElementsFor(EXTENSION_POINT);
    for (IConfigurationElement element : extensions) {
       [..]
    }
```

Is there a way to programmatically set up extension points so that I can construct a proper testing environment?

I would like to decouple those kind of tests from the UI and as far as possible, also from the Eclipse RCP framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there are no official APIs to add to the extension registry programmatically.

All the classes involved in adding to the extension registry are in internal packages so they should not be used.

Comment: What would be the recommended way to test classes that read data from the registry?

Comment: Sorry, but I have never looked at this sort of testing.

Comment: @kerner1000 you would create a test plug-in that contributes extensions. You have to be careful, though, since those extensions will exist for any other tests being run with that plug-in present.